# Python Files on Program Files and on AppData

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, path, mkdocs

I installed Python on Windows but it can't be recognized. Then I type `py --version` and my cmd can recognized python. When i check where my python is, it said:

1. c:/Program Files/Python311
2. c:~/AppData/Local/Windows/Python311

Then I uninstalled my Python and delete every folder related to python

I reinstall the python and tried to make sure there is only 1 folder of my python, and I checked so my python path can automatically be added.
I check my python.exe and its only on C:Program Files/Python311

I think finally everything is fine
But, when I tried to upgrade PIP, everything was fine. But, there is warning that said:

> WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.11.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
> Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Is it fine??
why python311 on Roaming now, before its on local under windows
I can't install MKDocs because its also saved on AppData/Roaming/Python/Python311/site-packages

Answer (score 0):

Python keeps its install on its versions. your 311 version is good, in system path. it recognized with py command, so no issues.
run a small sample test run using python:

==== Test code

---

cmd.exe
C:\user>py
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 4+5
9
>>>

---

```
</code>
```

Comment: Hi, my python can run the test code. When I check where python it saved on program files. But why my PIP saved on AppData/Roaming ?
Even there is python on Roaming?

Comment: So when I want to install MKDocs with PIP, windows can't recognized it